# C# ASP.NET Website To Image Bitmap

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, web

I found this code on StackOverflow.  & This code works great for converting a website to image.  However, instead of navigating to a new URL, can this code be modified to capture the current website?

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class WebsiteToImage
{
    private Bitmap m_Bitmap;
    private string m_Url;
    private string m_FileName = string.Empty;

    public WebsiteToImage(string url)
    {
        // Without file 
        m_Url = url;
    }

    public WebsiteToImage(string url, string fileName)
    {
        // With file 
        m_Url = url;
        m_FileName = fileName;
    }

    public Bitmap Generate()
    {
        // Thread 
        var m_thread = new Thread(_Generate);
        m_thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        m_thread.Start();
        m_thread.Join();
        return m_Bitmap;
    }

    private void _Generate()
    {
        var browser = new WebBrowser { ScrollBarsEnabled = false };
        browser.Navigate(m_Url);
        browser.DocumentCompleted += WebBrowser_DocumentCompleted;

        while (browser.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
        {
            Application.DoEvents();
        }

        browser.Dispose();
    }

    private void WebBrowser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Capture 
        var browser = (WebBrowser)sender;
        browser.ClientSize = new Size(browser.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Width, browser.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Bottom);
        browser.ScrollBarsEnabled = false;
        m_Bitmap = new Bitmap(browser.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Width, browser.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Bottom);
        browser.BringToFront();
        browser.DrawToBitmap(m_Bitmap, browser.Bounds);

       // Save as file? 
       if (m_FileName.Length > 0)
       {
           // Save 
           m_Bitmap.SaveJPG100(m_FileName);
       }
   }
```

}

```
public static class BitmapExtensions
{
    public static void SaveJPG100(this Bitmap bmp, string filename)
    {
        var encoderParameters = new EncoderParameters(1);
        encoderParameters.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality, 100L);
        bmp.Save(filename, GetEncoder(ImageFormat.Jpeg), encoderParameters);
    }

    public static void SaveJPG100(this Bitmap bmp, Stream stream)
    {
        var encoderParameters = new EncoderParameters(1);
        encoderParameters.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality, 100L);
        bmp.Save(stream, GetEncoder(ImageFormat.Jpeg), encoderParameters);
    }

    public static ImageCodecInfo GetEncoder(ImageFormat format)
    {
        var codecs = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageDecoders();

        foreach (var codec in codecs)
        {
            if (codec.FormatID == format.Guid)
            {
                return codec;
            }
         }

        // Return 
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: are you using ASP.NET MVC  ?

Comment: Yes I am using ASP.NET MVC.